# Identify important connecting node in a network

Tags: r

I have a list of bus stops and the number of buses running between two bus stops.The data looks like given below snap shot.

```
Bus Stop    Bus Stop    No of Buses
1   3   10
2   4   23
3   9   4
4   3   34
5   2   1
6   4   3
7   1   543
8   5   5
9   2   2
10  5   1
```

I need to identify important bus stops which connect the maximum bus routes.

How can I do in r.

I tried using arules package but could not identify the most important bus stop. Is there any other package in R which can help me to solve my problem.

Comment: So a bus stop's importance is the sum of the No of Buses column where that stop is in either of the first two columns?

Comment: Clearly stop 1 is the most important: It has 543 busses running to stop 7 (that's a lot of busses!) along with another 10 busses to stop 3.

Comment: You need to clearly identify what you mean by "importance".

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me you can use a graph to solve your problem.

Import your data:

```
dat <- read.table(text="
from    to    Number
1   3   10
2   4   23
3   9   4
4   3   34
5   2   1
6   4   3
7   1   543
8   5   5
9   2   2
10  5   1", header=TRUE)
```

Convert to a graph, using package `igraph` and plot

```
library(igraph)
p <- graph.data.frame(dat, directed=FALSE)
set.seed(42)
plot.igraph(p, edge.width=log1p(E(p)$Number))
```

[image]

It is quite apparent that edges 2, 3, 4, and 5 have three routes each.  You can establish that using the function `neighbors()`:

```
x <- sapply(V(p), function(i)length(neighbors(p, i)), USE.NAMES = TRUE)
x
## [1] 2 3 3 3 3 1 1 1 2 1

which(x == max(x))
## [1] 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: A nice synthetic visualization of all the weights could also be achieved with `get.adjacency(p, attr="Number")`.

Comment: Plus, if `A <- get.adjacency(p, attr="Number", sparse=F)`, then `sort(rowSums(A), decreasing=TRUE)` will sort the Bus Stops in decreasing order with respect to the total number of buses.

Comment: For some reason, I can't edit : it should be `plot.igraph(p,edge.width=log(E(p)$Number))+1)` (because log(1)=0).

Comment: @VincentGuillemot Thanks for your comments. I replaced `log()` with `log1p()` to reflect your suggestion.

Comment: Can anyone help me how to adjust the radius of the bubbles. Due to large data set I am not able to visualize anything.Also how can i remove the numbers from the visualization

Comment: @user2786962 See the help for `?igraph.plotting`. In particular, you need the arguments `vertex.size` and `vertex.label`. Try `plot.igraph(p, edge.width=log1p(E(p)$Number), vertex.size=20, vertex.label=NA)`

Comment: Thanks for the help..But I was trying this only and giving me the following error.plot.igraph(p,edge.width=0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001,vector.label=NA)
Error in i.parse.plot.params(graph, list(...)) : 
  Unknown plot parameters: vector.label

Comment: @user2786962 Use vertex.label